# FFMPEG: Reversing only a segment of a video file

Tags: ffmpeg

I am writing a script that takes a piece of video and then reverses the same piece of video and then concats the two together so the final video plays forwards and then loops backwards. I should note that eventually I want to be able to pull an unequal length for the reverse part.

I can get the entire file to do this, but getting just a segment is not working as expected.

See code below

I've tried:

%1 = timecode to seek to (the video file is only 20 seconds and never any longer)

%2 = length of segment to pull out

%3 = usually the same as %2 but may be different if we want to only reverse 2 seconds instead of the full 5 for example.

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:00:%1 -an -i test.mp4 -t 00:00:%2 out.mp4
:: the above works as expected

:: this doesn't, no matter what I put into -ss. I've also tried moving -ss out front of the -i as suggested in the documentation? It gives me the right length of segment but never starts in the right place. 

ffmpeg  -an -i test.mp4 -ss 00:00:xx -t 00:00:%3 -vf reverse reversed2.mp4

:the below works fine
ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i mylist.txt -c copy output.mp4
```

When I run this with say %1 = 05 and %2 = 05, I get a segment from 5 seconds in that lasts 5 seconds. Then I get a seemingly random starting point and 5 seconds of reversed video. I've tried a number of inputs in "XX" from 10 (which I think is right) to 0 to 19 and all of them produce output. But it's all wrong.

Comment: Interacting with application programs at the command line is an off-topic *usage* question.  Only questions about developing/modifying their actual source code would be on-topic here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe `-ss` and `-t` don't work in conjunction with this video-filter.

> I am writing a script that takes a piece of video and then reverses the same piece of video and then concats the two together so the final video plays forwards and then loops backwards.

You'd have to use `-lavfi`, or `-filter_complex`:

```
ffmpeg -i test.mp4 -lavfi ^
trim=5:10,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS,split[v1][v2]; ^
[v2]reverse[v2a]; ^
[v1][v2a]concat=n=2:v=1:a=0 ^
-an loop.mp4
```

- Grab the video piece between 5s and 10s in time, reset the timestamps and create 2 indentical outputs.
  `trim=start=5:duration=5` also works. `trim=start=00:00:05:duration=00:00:05` does not.
- Reverse the video using 1 of `split`'s outputs.
- Concatenate `split`'s other output and the reversed video (2 segments, 1 video, 0 audio).

Comment: thank you. That is a much more eloquent solution than what I came up with.